# How do I click on a dynamically loaded link?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am currently working on web automation via Selenium.

I have a html file where the relevant part is this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tabon" nowrap="">
                <div class="tabon">
                    <a id="tab" href="(long dynamically generated string)">
                        <b>Main Page</b>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="taboff" nowrap="">
                <div class="taboff">
                    <a id="tab" href="(another long string)">Info</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to access the second tab. Using Selenium I can't actually "click" on the div tag.

```
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ('error')
```

This always results in an error. It has something to do with the fact that when the div tag is interacted with, it clicks on the URL anchor which changes the div such that the clicked on tag has a "tabon" property. How can Selenium mimic this?

**EDIT: I neglected to note that the class with "tabon" has the title of the page in a separate bold tag.**

Comment: Is the tab "info" visible on the webpage ?

Comment: Yes. http://picpaste.com/Untitled-XD1Gydt3.png

Comment: Looks like you want to click on "My Info" tab.. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. The example code isn't a perfect reflection of the actual site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, in case the tab "My Info" is visible on the webpage:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='My Info']").click()
```

**This will click on the element with tag 'a' and having exact innerHTML/text as *My Info*.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to be passing click on `a` tag not on `div` and in addition to the solution **Subh** provided you can use `.taboff a` as `cssselector`. This selector walks you down to `a` tag from second `td` of pasted `html`